# IIS - Redirect all requests from one domain to a specific folder

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a website configured on IIS and multiple domains configured on my hosts file to point to my localhost.

My problem is that I need to redirect all the requests from:
http://domain.com/folder/ to http://domain.com/

So a request for 
http://domain.com/folder/test/image.jpeg should be transformed into:
http://domain.com/test/image.jpeg

I can't change the files because I'm trying to emulate a cdn behavior.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Joao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module), you can go with:

```
<rule name="skip folder" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The default redirect is a permanent (301).
If you want to keep the url `http://domain.com/folder/test/image.jpeg` but display the content `http://domain.com/test/image.jpeg`, then a rewrite has to be used:

```
<rule name="skip folder" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```